# NativeScript Angular screen qualifier SCSS files

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've been unsuccessful at getting screen qualifiers to work in Angular.

I'm using the `nativescript-dev-sass` to transpile `SCSS` files to `CSS` files.

The component is compiled before being deployed to the device.

Extract of the transpiled component `TypeScript`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'plugin-user-login',
    templateUrl: 'user-login.component.ns.html',
    styleUrls: ['user-login.component.ns.css'],
    moduleId: module.id
})
```

I'd like the component `TypeScript` file to select different `CSS` files based on the device's size at runtime.

Is it possible to create a selector for the `styleUrls`?

Is there a solution for screen qualifier labelled `SCSS` files to be used at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this is supported in the stock NativeScript projects, but not for NativeScript Angular projects.

If you are open to adjusting your development stack, I would suggest utilizing the angular native seed developed by Team Maestro.

https://github.com/TeamMaestro/angular-native-seed

There has been additional tooling added to the seed to allow you to specify phone/tablet templates.

If you need more specific control than phone vs tablet layouts, I would suggest an alternative approach. You could get the device size in the main AppComponent, then append a class to your component (i.e. `.size-468`, so that you can style based on that size.

Downsides: Does not accomplish what you are asking for, with having a separate CSS file for different screen sizes. You could abstract stylesheets out and import them or use SASS syntax to extend classes based on my previous paragraph.

If you are curious to "why" this problem exists. It's because NativeScript does not know the size of the device running the application, until runtime. Angular builds the templates ahead of time (AOT), therefor there's no intelligent way currently to know what stylesheet or template to load instead.

Disclosure: I am one of the primary developers on the Angular Native Seed.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague assisted me with the following solution.

Create a function to replace / edit the `styleUrls` `String[]`

```
export function switchStyleUrls(styleUrl: string): string {

    switch (Platform.deviceSize()) {
        case DeviceSizeE.dpi326:
            return styleUrl.replace(".css", ".minWH326.css");

        case DeviceSizeE.dpi401:
            return styleUrl.replace(".css", ".minWH401.css");

        case DeviceSizeE.default:
            return styleUrl;
    }
}
```

The `Platform.deviceSize()` returns the `DeviceSizeE` based on `platformModule.screen.mainScreen.widthPixels`

---

Pass in the `switchStyleUrls` function into the `Component` `Decorators` `styleUrls` `String[]`

```
@Component({
    selector: './plugin-user-login',
    templateUrl: './user-login.component.web.html',
    styleUrls: [switchStyleUrls('../plugin-user.scss')],
    moduleId: module.id
})
```

It's my understanding that the `styleUrls` `string[]` is resolved during the build.

I'm still testing this solution.